# Is an auth token in query string the only solution for a simple get request?

Tags: security, access-token

I am using JWT to authenticate and authorize requests made by a Single Page Application.

During the navigation in the application, I use XMLHttpRequest so I am able to set a header and use the token like this:

```
headers:
Authorization: Bearer MyJWTToken
```

However, I sometimes **need to download a protected file in that application** so I have to provide a link like this one where I can't set any header:

```
<a target="_blank" href="/api/protected-uri?access_token=MyJWTToken">Download Invoice</a>
```

I read that using the token in the query string is not secure at all because it could end in the server logs or in the user browser history.

**However, I can't see any other solution. Is this really a bad practice? How to bypass this problem? Should I make use of the browser cookies?**

Comment: What did you end up doing here? I would think having a token end up in logs is really only an issue if it contains some particularly interesting information/claims. I'm facing a similar issue and want to use a token as a way of identifying a request source from an authorized and authenticated user, but I don't need to pass anything valuable in the token. One other thing that might be of use in this scenario is the idea of a [single use token](https://www.jbspeakr.cc/howto-single-use-jwt/). That might be applicable in only certain scenarios, but it is an interesting idea.

Comment: I ended up setting a cookie on the client when I get the token.. I don't really like this solution but it works. Your idea of a single use token is cool, except that it makes the link not sharable. If you find anything else in the future, I would be very happy to hear it

Answer (score 0):

What I would do (and have done) is link to an application route that then redirects the user to the appropriate destination. This way you avoid including auth data in the rendered HTML page.